# How to to reduce startup time and memory consumption of a java program?

Tags: java, performance, memory

I assume the latest update version of java would provide better performance.

I am looking for a way to implement isolation of software components from endless loops or memory leaks. Android isolates each app in it's own process, Google Chrome isolates each tab in it's own process.

My primary drawback is that `java` takes so long to start and also I would like to reduce memory consumption.

Is there any alternate build or more controlled startup that will accomplish this?

Comment: What kind of a java program are we talking about here, desktop, web app? Is it actually java that is the problem or is it just your program?

Comment: Test it with a profiler to find out for sure

Comment: It is a web app, but I cannot tell much about it. On java 5, if you have nothing but a main class with main method and println then it still takes a moment to get that println to write to the screen (where you could get it instantly with `echo` or `date` or other commands). The memory question is not as important as the startup time question.

Comment: Also you can reduce memory usage by supplying a lower max memory setting at the CLI.  use -Xmx to set the most memory you will allow your VM to use.  To optimize performance, Java will often allocate much more than it needs.

Comment: A web app should start up 1 time per week (give or take), and sit on a web server running. If the startup time of a web app is a problem to you, then you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If quick startup is your goal, Java on a PC may not be your best bet.  It's going to take a few seconds because that's how long it takes to load the VM from disk.

If you want your app to start more quickly it's easy to get a splash screen up, just create a module that only loads your splash screen, waits for it to fully display then uses reflection to link to your "Real" main module.

(Use reflection because otherwise it will pull in your entire program through references before it starts the main one--at least that's how it used to work).

If you're talking about run-time performance, you won't get quicker by changing languages, Java's about as fast as you can get.  You MIGHT be able to get a boost by converting to C/C++ and rewriting it to suit those platforms (Less OO, stack allocations instead of heap, etc), but otherwise none of the other languages in general usage are close to Java in speed.

If you really need the quick startup, depending on what you are doing there may be some tricks.  I've seen projects that try to keep a Java VM running in your toolbar and allow you to make requests (tell it to start an app).  This was faster but made additional requirements of the user (Loading this additional tool)

Another possibility--if you are constantly starting up/shutting down small tasks and that's the reason the startup bothers you then you can definitely speed it up by keeping it running invisibly.  Just have your Java app open a socket and listen for commands then create a little .EXE or shell script that can start your program if it's not running or send commands to that socket if it is.  This would completely eliminate startups after the first run.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Java has a much longer startup time than other languages. If you are sticking with Java on a desktop app, a lot of stuff like startup time is determined by the JRE installed on the client's computer, which you can't control.

As to "endless memory leaks"... Java doesn't leak memory. If your program does, fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a second answer because it's completely different and my other got too long :)

Try compiling it--I think GCC can compile it.  This could almost completely eliminate your startup.  I believe Jikes used to be a windows java compiler by IBM, but I don't know if it's still maintained.

Note that compiled code will probably run slower than JVM code for long-running apps.